# How to replace text within two words on TextWrangler?

Tags: macos, text-editors, text-editing, textwrangler

I have a large XML file with hundreds of thousands of lines, and I need to replace data between two words (tags, in reality).

Ex.:

```
<foo>Sample Text</foo>
```

Where I need to replace "Sample Text" in-between the  tags.

I'd like to replace the text between the "<foo>" tags, and since there are thousands of lines with the "<foo>" tag, and hundreds of differences in the data within these tags, I'd need to use the Find and Replace function, but the issue is that I'm not sure how to replace the data within the tags.

Answer (score 0):

Simply type the following into the Find dialog (Apple-F or pull down Search - Find).

[image]

Then click on the 'Replace All' button.